# Is fuzzy search in CosmosDB ARRAY_CONTAINS possible?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to search a CosmosDB Array using array contains as follows

```
SELECT c.id, c.PromotionName FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Variants, '0828570001006')
```

This works fine but I cannot figure out how to make the value fuzzy so that I can match on only the first 7 digits so the query would look like below

```
SELECT c.id, c.PromotionName FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Variants, '0828570')
```

But still match the same as the query above ( and more )

Is this possible?

Comment: `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` is only going to give you exact matches (whether a scalar array or an array of documents). You can use `STARTSWITH()` but not within `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`. There's nothing built-in to provide what you're looking for.

Comment: If you want fuzzy search you need something that supports Lucene type queries such as Azure Search. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a search where you check if the variants in your array start with a certain string like this:

```sql
select c.id, c.PromotionName
from c
where exists (
    select value true
    from v in c.Variants
    where startswith(v, '0828570')
)
```

> Note that this is not a fuzzy search.